# Position the cursor to the end of the string in Ionic Windows platform

Tags: ionic-framework, input, focus, autofocus

I have this HTML code

`<ion-searchbar #searchBar></ion-searchbar>`

JS code

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class HomePage {

    @ViewChild('searchBar') myInput;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

        ionViewDidLoad() {
            setTimeout(() => {
            this.myInput.setFocus();
        }, 150)

    }

}
```

The searchBar input field gets focused. How to get the cursor (caret) point to the end of the string in #searchBar?

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/setting-focus-to-an-input-in-ionic/62789/4

Focus always set the cursor at the end of the content

Comment: I forgot to mention the searchbar is rendered inside a modal.